# Is there any Javascript document viewer engine with text highlighting API?

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript doc viewing engine with some text highlighting API.

Can you advise anything?

Comment: do you want to display a word document or pdf..???

Comment: Both. I need something like ViewerJS. But it doesn't seem to have such API. Basically I want to be able to index those documents (e.g. highlight section from index A  to index B, scroll to a certain index or or return index of selected or clicked section or point.

Answer (score 0):

give try to **WebODF** it is a JavaScript library that add Open Edit Document Format (ODF) support to your website and to your mobile or desktop application. It uses HTML and CSS to display ODF documents.
and opensource also :)

http://webodf.org/